# PMF of total score in a card matching game

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

Consider a deck of cards with ​$N$​ different playing cards equally distributed among  $M$ suits (e.g., $N=52, M=4$). You draw all the cards without putting any back. After the first card, each time you pick a card, you compare it to the previous card. If the suits match, you get ONE point; otherwise, you get no point. Suppose $P$ is the total points you get at the end of this process.

I am trying to calculate the PMF of $P$ so that I can calculate some statistics such as mean, standard deviation, etc. Here what I've gone so far:

Suppose $P_i, ~~i=1, 2, ..., N$ is the value of $P$ at the end of $i$th draw. Obviously, $P_1=0$. Also, suppose $m_i\in\{1, 2, ..., M\}, ~~i=1, 2, ..., N$ is the suit of the $i$th card that we have drawn. According to the rules, $P_{i+1} = P_i + 1$ if and only if $m_{i+1} = m_i$, i.e., $Pr(P_{i+1} = P_i + 1)=Pr(m_{i+1} = m_i)$.

Let's consider $M=52, N=4$. The probability of picking the first card is $Pr(m_1=k)=\frac{M}{N}=\frac{1}{13}, ~~k=1, 2, 3, 4$. For the second draw, we have:

$Pr(m_2=k)=
  \begin{cases}
             \frac{\frac{M}{N}-1}{N-1}=\frac{12}{51} &~~ \text{$k=m_1$} \\
             \frac{\frac{M}{N}}{N-1}=\frac{13}{51} &~~ \text{$k\neq m_1$} \\
  \end{cases}$  $~~~~~~$ 
$\Rightarrow Pr(P_{2} = P_1 + 1)=Pr(m_2=m_1)=\frac{12}{51}$

However, I can't proceed with the third and higher draws as I should include th previous cards until the first one into the expression.

I have used the following MATLAB code to simulate the experiment:

```
n = 1e6; N = 52; M = 4;
P = zeros(1, n);
for i = 1:n
    I = randi([1 M], 1, N);
    P(i) = sum(([I(2:end), 0]-I)==0);
end
disp(['Mean of P for N = 52 and M = 4:  ' num2str(mean(P))]);
disp(['Standard deviation of P for N = 52 and M = 4:  ' num2str(std(P))]);
disp(['Pr(P>12 | P>6) for N = 52 and M = 4:  ' num2str(sum(P>12)/sum(P>6))]);
```

Comment: With $N=52, M=4$ the lowest possible value of $P$ is $0$ isn't it? How do you get $2$?

Comment: This is quite a complicated problem. Are you sure you need the entire distribution? The statistics that you list (mean and standard deviation) are by comparison almost trivial to calculate. Do you need any others?

Comment: What I need at the end of the day is the mean and standard deviation. Could you help me with them? @joriki

Comment: @sammygerbil I ran random simulations thousands of times and the minimum was 2.

Comment: @jurel: But you can clearly just cycle through the suits without ever having a match. I suspect that was just too improbable to show up if you only ran a couple of thousand simulations.

Comment: @joriki: I think you are right. I edited the post and removed that part. How about the mean and standard deviation?

Comment: I'm writing it out :-)

Comment: @joriki : Thank you very much. Could you give me a hint on how to calculate $Pr(P>12 | P>6)$ too?

Comment: @jurel: I'm afraid that's right up there with the computing the entire distribution. I'd use a computer for that. Anything that can be expressed in terms of expectations is easy (because of the linearity of expectation, which doesn't require independence) – everything that depends on the details of the correlations between different matches is complicated. To get an approximation of that probability, you can approximate the distribution by a normal distribution with the same mean and variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll use $R=\frac NM$ for the number of ranks so as not to have to carry around that fraction.

Consider the indicator variable $I_k$ for $1\le k\lt N$ that is $1$ if the suits of cards $k$ and $k+1$ match and $0$ otherwise. Then the number of matches is $X=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}I_k$. Using the linearity of expectation, the expectation of $X$ can be calculated as

\begin{eqnarray}
E[X]
&=&
E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}I_k\right]
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}E\left[I_k\right]
\\
&=&
(N-1)\frac{M\binom R2}{\binom N2}
\\
&=&
R-1\;.
\end{eqnarray}

So for a standard deck of $52$ cards in $4$ suits and $13$ ranks, this would be $12$.

The variance can be expressed in terms of expectations and calculated similarly:

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Var}[X]
&=&
E\left[X^2\right]-E\left[X\right]^2
\\
&=&
E\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}I_k\right)^2\right]-(R-1)^2
\\
&=&
E\left[\sum_{j,k=1}^{N-1}I_jI_k\right]-(R-1)^2
\\
&=&
\sum_{j,k=1}^{N-1}E\left[I_jI_k\right]-(R-1)^2
\\
&=&
(N-1)E\left[I_1I_1\right]+2(N-2)E\left[I_1I_2\right]+(N-2)(N-3)E\left[I_1I_3\right]-(R-1)^2
\end{eqnarray}

In the first term, $I_1I_1=I_1$, so this is just $E[X]=R-1$. In the second term, $I_1$ and $I_2$ are both $1$ if the suits of three consecutive cards match, with probability

$$
\frac{M\binom R3}{\binom N3}=\frac{MR(R-1)(R-2)}{N(N-1)(N-2)}=\frac{(R-1)(R-2)}{(N-1)(N-2)}\;.
$$

In the third term, $I_1$ and $I_3$ are both one if either all four cards involved are of the same suit, with probability

$$
\frac{M\binom R4}{\binom N4}=\frac{MR(R-1)(R-2)(R-3)}{N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)}=\frac{(R-1)(R-2)(R-3)}{(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)}\;,
$$

or the two cards for $I_1$ are of one suit and the two for $I_3$ are of another, with probability

$$
\frac{M(M-1)\binom R2\binom R2}{\binom N2\binom{N-2}2}=\frac{M(M-1)R^2(R-1)^2}{N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)}=\frac{(M-1)R(R-1)^2}{(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)}\;.
$$

Putting it all together, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Var}[X]
&=&
R-1+\frac{2(R-1)(R-2)}{N-1}+\frac{(R-1)(R-2)(R-3)}{N-1}+\frac{(M-1)R(R-1)^2}{(N-1)}-(R-1)^2
\\
&=&
\frac{(N-R)(R-1)}{N-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

So for a standard deck of $52$ cards in $4$ suits and $13$ ranks, this would be $\frac{156}{17}\approx9.18$. (The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.) [Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/0101f1d6672faf32ed71926b47aa0c96) that checks these results by simulation.

---

*P.S.*:

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/500226cd6f9a7475cb56e67febdd8553) that calculates the exact probability distribution. The result for a standard deck of $52$ cards in $4$ suits and $13$ ranks is (in the range where the probabilities are at least $0.1\%$):

\begin{array}{c|cc}
x&P(X=x)\\\hline
4&0.3\%\\
5&0.7\%\\
6&1.8\%\\
7&3.5\%\\
8&5.8\%\\
9&8.6\%\\
10&11.1\%\\
11&12.7\%\\
12&13.1\%\\
13&12.1\%\\
14&10.1\%\\
15&7.7\%\\
16&5.3\%\\
17&3.4\%\\
18&1.9\%\\
19&1.0\%\\
20&0.5\%\\
21&0.2\%\\
\end{array}

In particular,

$$
P(X\gt6)=\frac{423184664000229408829}{435551802585870927936}\approx97.2\%\;,\\[10pt]
P(X\gt12)=\frac{25587624310904056432013593}{60410740726901793737880000}\approx42.4\%\;,\\[10pt]
P(X\gt12\mid X\gt6)=\frac{946742099503450087984502941}{2171730797566177297434324375}\approx43.6\%
$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Could you please explain why $E[I_k]$ is equal to $\frac{M\binom R2}{\binom N2}$ for all $k$?

Comment: I simulated the experiment thousands of thousands of times using MATLAB and the results for the variance was very close to the ones you calculated analytically. However, the results of the mean values were not. For example, for $M=52, N=4$, the value of variance resulted from the simulation was $9.5485$, while that of the analytical answer is $9.1765$. The value of the mean resulted from the simulation was $12.7461$, while that of the analytical answer is $12$. What do you suggest?

Comment: @jurel: I suggest that there's apparently an error either in my calculation or in your simulation :-). I'll go over it again...

Comment: :  I just added the code snippet I used for simulation to the first post. Could you please check it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @jurel: I wrote my own simulation and I get $12$ (and also the right variance, about $9.18$), so I suspect the error must be in your code. I'll take a look at it. You might want to add the language it's written in to the post.

Comment: Thank you. Mine is a MATLAB code (I added the language to the post). I will be grateful if you could add your simulation code (or pseudo-code) to your answer.

Comment: @jurel: You're not actually simulating a deck of cards at all. You're just drawing $N$ independent suits. The probability for a match in that case is simply $\frac1M$, so the expected number of matches is $\frac{N-1}M$, so $12.75$ for a standard deck, in agreement with your simulation. If this is the experiment you're interested, you don't need a simulation for that; it's just $N-1$ independent Bernoulli variables, for which statistics (including $P(X\gt12\mid X\gt6)$) are easy to calculate.

Comment: @jurel: I've added a link to my code at the end of my answer.

Comment: @jurel: I wrote code to compute the full probability distribution; see the end of the answer.

Comment: Your answers were very detailed and complete. Thank you for your time @joriki